# How to solve the sleeping problem in Quartz.NET (C #)?

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I am having a problem with Quartz.NET to create a job on a system. The Quartz is sleeping 23:50 and waking up 7:26 AM.

I have a job scheduled for 00:00

System Information: 1 - .NET Application 2 - IIS Server

Application log:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6vdH.png)

Comment: What is the sleeping problem?

Comment: I have a job scheduled for 00:00,IIS wake up 7:20 AM

Answer (score 0):

I personally just use quartz job calculator the set job execute time when server is up

https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html

and have the ability to manually start them later if needed.

You can also create a job that automates this. For example it runs every 10m that checks if some other job has to be run. It does so by checking when it was last ran, and if it is ran it will set a sync lock - a simple local time, so you can check if some amount of time ex: 1 day has passed.